# open a link in IE from edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript, microsoft-edge

I have created a function where the user is not using IE and using edge, and then click on a given link they will get an error message saying, this site is not compatible with edge, Please use IE. However is there a way to open IE from this error message?. have inserted an IE image on the error message. However, I was thinking of making the image clickable. Can this be accomplished with the following link? 
When I type in the link in the search bar, the link does not work. Is there a way to accomplish this? Any help is extremely appreciated!

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.yahoo.com/" 


<div class="modal-body" align="center"  >

                                <h3>edge Browser is not Supported</h3>
                                <p>To use yahoo, please use IE</p>
                                <a href = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.yahoo.com/"> <img src="../Images/IE.jpg" width=80 height=85 />
                            </div>
```

Comment: Luckily, no. Imagine if you could just run any local application from a website. It wouldn't be very secure, don't you think?

Comment: Maybe link them to the download site for IE instead and they can decide to download IE (if they don't have it) or not

Comment: On Company networks You can manage which sites use IE11 and which sites use Edge with Enterprise Site Mode Lists.